# Does JDK 7 use non-contiguous heap?

Tags: java, java-7, jvm-hotspot, jrockit

I am aware that JDK 7 is supposed to be a merger between hotspot and jrockit and that there will not be a jrockit 1.7. (Source: https://blogs.oracle.com/henrik/entry/java_7_questions_answers) I have a project that requires the non-contiguous heap feature of jrockit as well as some java 1.7 features, so since JDK 7 is a merger, does it support non-contiguous heap because I can't find an offical documentation which says so?

Comment: Is your question not answered, on the page you link to, under the question "Will the converged JVM get the feature that allows JRockit to allocate more heap on Windows?"

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are asking about non-contiguous heaps because you are suffering from memory fragmentation. A lot of the time your 32-bit address space is fragmented, but your 64-bit address space is not. Meaning, if your computer has sufficient memory, using a 64-bit JVM will allow you to find contiguous memory that a 32-bit JVM will not. I have personally used a 64-bit JVM to allocate heaps over 4GB when a 32-bit JVM failed to allocate a heap over 2GB.

Although it doesn't look like arbitrary non-contiguous heaps made it into JDK 7, you can try using the G1 garbage collector. According to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/g1-intro-jsp-135488.html:

> The heap is partitioned into a set of equal-sized heap regions, each a contiguous range of virtual memory.

Theoretically speaking, this allows you to play with a non-contiguous heap. The only limitation is that the regions must be of equal size.

According to http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/G1GettingStarted/index.html#t6 you can use this command-line option to control the region size:

> **-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=n**: With G1 the Java heap is subdivided into uniformly sized regions. This sets the size of the individual sub-divisions. The default value of this parameter is determined ergonomically based upon heap size. The minimum value is 1Mb and the maximum value is 32Mb.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sounds good, but i made a few tests and it behaved the same. They probably mean that the contiguous heap is partitioned for better GC.
But something is odd. I specified 1g and visualVM is showing me a maximum of 2g...